# Document.querySelector: '#categories_description[1]' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

I have an error appear and I can not understand what happened with the script, sorry, I am a beginner. `Document.querySelector: '#categories_description[1]' is not a valid selector`

```
for ($i = 0, $n = \count($languages); $i < $n; $i++) {
    $name = 'categories_description[' . $languages[$i]['id'] . ']';
    echo HTML::textAreaCkeditor($name, 'soft', '750', '300', (isset($categories_description[$languages[$i]['id']]) ? str_replace('& ', '&amp; ', trim($categories_description[$languages[$i]['id']])) : $CategoriesAdmin->getCategoryDescription($cInfo->categories_id, $languages[$i]['id'])), 'id="' . $name . '"'); ?>
```

Now on ckeditor

```
ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#" . HTML::output($name) . "') , {
        toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'imageUpload', 'ckfinder', 'blockQuote', 'insertTable', 'mediaEmbed', 'undo', 'redo', '|', 'help']
    } )
   ....
```

The problem seems tocome there : `document.querySelector('#" . HTML::output($name)')` dot accept the php array

I also tried this, does not work

`$id = HTML::output($name)`;

```
ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#{$id}') , {
        toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'imageUpload', 'ckfinder', 'blockQuote', 'insertTable', 'mediaEmbed', 'undo', 'redo', '|', 'help']
    } )
```

Thank you

Comment: You should not use the ID attribute anymore, instead you can use the class to mark and put the CKeditor initialization out of the loop.
ClassicEditor
     .create(document.querySelector('.textarea_class_name') , {....

Answer (score 0):

You're using an [attribute selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors) but it isn't clear why.

If you are trying to select an element with an attribute named `1` then… redesign your markup. Attribute names are not permitted to start with numbers in XML and HTML has no `1` attribute.

If you are trying to select an element with `[` and `]` characters in the ID value, then you need to escape those characters (`#foo\[1\]`) (keeping in mind that `\` is an escape character for both selectors and string literals so you will need to double escape).

Answer (score 0):

You're PHP is producing something like this:

```
ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#categories_description[1]'));
```

The problem is square brackets `[]` in CSS selectors are used to [select HTML element attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), like this:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("input[type='text']").value);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="hide" value="nope">
<input type="text" name="val" value="ok">
```

So when the Javascript engine hits the first square bracket, `'#categories_description[`, <-- here, it starts the process to look for HTML element attributes within the element having `id="categories_description"`. Next it looks in the square brackets and expects to find a valid key="value" pair such as `type="text"`, or `name="categories_description[1]"`. These are valid selectors:

```
document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
document.querySelector('input[name="categories_description[1]"]');
```

...and even this is a valid CSS selector:

```
document.querySelector('[id="categories_description[1]"]');
```

So if you need to use square brackets in your `id` name, this will produce a valid CSS selector in the code you provided:

```
echo 'ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector(\'[id="' . HTML::output($name) . '"]\');';
```

---

But if you're using a hash `#` or a dot `.` in your selector, it then becomes necessary to double escape `\\` square brackets in Javascript when selecting a CSS selector that contains them. Starting with what Javascript needs to see:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#div\\[1\\]").textContent);
```

```html
<div id="div[1]">hey</div>
```

And to use PHP to write this Javascript, you need to escape each backslash in PHP:

```
<?php

echo 'console.log(document.querySelector("#div\\\\[1\\\\]").textContent);';

?>
```

Here's a brief example of a PHP `for` loop that writes the HTML element and the corresponding Javascript:

```
<?php

for ( $ii = 0; $ii < 4; $ii++ ) {
    echo <<< EOT

<div id="div[$ii]">abc</div>

<script>
ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector("#div\\\\[$ii\\\\]"));
</script>

EOT;
}

?>
```

...produces:

```
<div id="div[0]">abc</div>

<script>
ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector("#div\\[0\\]"));
</script>

<div id="div[1]">abc</div>

<script>
ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector("#div\\[1\\]"));
</script>

<div id="div[2]">abc</div>

<script>
ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector("#div\\[2\\]"));
</script>

<div id="div[3]">abc</div>

<script>
ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector("#div\\[3\\]"));
</script>
```